# Загрузка файла на сервер Vue js

Tags: vue.js, yii2, файлы, post

В общем, вопрос такой: Загружаю файлы на с vue js через axios из массива attached.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.set("name", this.Form.name);
formData.set("from", this.Form.from);
formData.set("subject", this.Form.subject);
formData.set("subject", this.Form.text);
formData.append("files", this.attached);
this.readFormData(formData)

axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "/mail/",
    headers: { "Content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
    data: formData,
});
```

Но на сервер файл приходит, как строка '[object file]', а не сам объект. Хотя в массиве attached лежит объект. бэкенд на yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно документации на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0_formdata) Вы не можете отправить массив файлов, Вам нужно явно указать какой файл Вы хотите отправить.

```
// Файл, выбранный пользователем
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);
```